# Python - Sorting the values of every row in a table and get a new Pandas dataframe with original column index/labels in sorted sequence in each row

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I just have a table in csv format like this

| Date | Company1 | Company2 | Company3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | 1,01 | 0,9 | 1 |
| 02.01.2020 | 0,9 | 2,2 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 24.10.2020 | 1,02 | 1,01 | 1,03 |

Now my aim is to sort every row in a descending order. So I finally get the following table:

| Date | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | Company1 | Company3 | Company2 |
| 02.01.2020 | Company2 | Company3 | Company1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 24.10.2020 | Company3 | Company1 | Company2 |

is their a simple way to do something with python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on each row to sort values in descending order and get the index (i.e. column labels) of sorted sequence:

```
df2 = (df.set_index('Date')[['Company1', 'Company2', 'Company3']]
         .replace(r',', r'.', regex=True)
         .astype(float)
         .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).index.tolist(), axis=1, result_type='expand')
         .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns+1, axis=1))
         .reset_index()
      )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df2)


         Date         1         2         3
0  01.01.2020  Company1  Company3  Company2
1  02.01.2020  Company2  Company3  Company1
2  24.10.2020  Company3  Company1  Company2
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach using [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

```
# get column names
columns = df.columns[1:].to_numpy()

# get sorted indices
indices = np.argsort(df.iloc[:, 1:] * -1, axis=1)

# create new DataFrame
res = pd.concat([df["Date"], pd.DataFrame(columns[indices], columns=range(1, 4))], axis=1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
         Date         1         2         3
0  01.01.2020  Company1  Company3  Company2
1  02.01.2020  Company2  Company3  Company1
2  24.10.2020  Company3  Company1  Company2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use reshape using `melt`, `sort_values` and create a helper column, then shape back to original with the helper column as column names:

```
(df.melt(id_vars='Date')
   .sort_values(by='value', ascending=False)
   .assign(col=lambda d: d.groupby('Date').cumcount().add(1))
   .pivot(index='Date', columns='col', values='variable')
)
```

output:

```
col                1         2         3
Date                                    
01.01.2020  Company1  Company3  Company2
02.01.2020  Company2  Company3  Company1
24.10.2020  Company3  Company1  Company2
```