# Python: Get sorting position of the values of every row in a table

Tags: python, sorting, matrix

Based on my Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69698283/python-sorting-the-values-of-every-row-in-a-table-and-get-a-new-pandas-datafra) ist there a way to transform the Matrix based on a .csv-file

| Date | Company1 | Company2 | Company3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | 1.01 | 0.9 | 1 |
| 02.01.2020 | 0.9 | 2.2 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 24.10.2020 | 1.02 | 1.01 | 1.03 |

into a .csv-file of form

| Date | Company1 | Company2 | Company3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 02.01.2020 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 24.10.2020 | 2 | 3 | 1 |

Whereby Companyx gets:

- value 1, iff companyx has the biggest value in the base matrix on given date y
- value 2, iff companyx has the middle value in the base matrix on given date y
- value 3, iff companyx has the smallest value in the base matrix on given date y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in rank function to solve this problem, passing `axis=1` to indicate a row-wise ranking.

```
df.set_index('Date').rank(axis=1, ascending=False).reset_index()
```

Output

```
         Date  Company1  Company2  Company3
0  01.01.2020       1.0       3.0       2.0
1  02.01.2020       3.0       1.0       2.0
2  24.10.2020       2.0       3.0       1.0
```